# What is the priority? CSS3>jQuery or CSS3<jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Weird things are happening in my code. Firstly i have CSS3 transform skew(25deg) on my `special link`. What i want is to keep this transform during `.click` event and reset the transform on second `.click` using simple jQuery code. 
jQuery code works on an element without implemented transform but it doesn't have any effect on the element that has transform skew implemented. Is there any priority? How does browser see this?

https://jsfiddle.net/34ho1fd9/9/ <--with jQuery and transform skew (no jQuery effect)
http://jsfiddle.net/9KK65/ <-- simple jQuery .click effect which works on element without CSS3

Comment: jQuery. jQuery uses the `style` attribute. That attribute has precedence to **ANY** other style. That's the answer to the title.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel is right. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: I see, thanks for information and confirmation!

Comment: If CSS was stronger than jQuery it would make jQuery basically useless.

Comment: @Juhana Not to mention all the libraries to deal with CSS and animations. Those wouldn't work at all.

Comment: css can be stronger with the `!important` tag

Comment: What's with the coding webkit transforms only...

Answer (score 0):

Priority is always given to the `<style>` tag first.

jQuery is stronger than CSS in that regard; it can override CSS styles with its own.